# .Net Workflows: hide property of activity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity, .net

I use a workflow with custom activities:

public class isOkActivity : System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity

This is the base-Type of some of my activities.

In the designer-view of my workflow all of that public properties are shown (and executed).

One of that properties does some heavy database-procedures which I do not want to be executed each time I work in the Workflow.

Is there any way to hide that property for the designer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: Change that property to a method. If it does some heavy database work it isn't supposed to be a property anyway as properties should be light in nature.

If you don't want to do that, you can at least stop the database queries if you are in design mode using [`Activity.DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.dependencyobject.designmode.aspx):

```
public bool CanRun
{
    get
    {
        if(DesignMode)
            return false;

        // your database stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I have reasons to use a property there. (Reflection is one of them) Also: The purpose of that value is just a property. It is a boolean showing if the activitiy should be run. "Feels" more like a property than a method to me.

Comment: @OleAlbers: The fact that it does "some heavy work" is surprising to users of the class. I would make it a method for this very reason.

Comment: Ok. "Heavy" work was perhaps a bit exaggerated. :) It does a select on a database which is just to much as nearly every activity does that and I just don't want DB-Operations in designer